# Retrieving relevant posts from Wordpress blogs

Tags: wordpress, search, web-crawler

I have a requirement to write a program in Java to retrieve all the posts from all the wordpress sites containing a keyword(s). 
This is how I approached the problem. I initially thought I would crawl the wordpress sites looking for the keywords I am interested in. But I realized if there is an endpoint for wordpress search, it makes my job a lot easier. So I have looked around to see if there is any search endpoint to submit queries and get the links for the posts.
All I found is just http://wwww.en.search.wordpress.com. I can still tweak the url and get some links. But

1. I like to know if there is any better way to handle this problem
2. The search link I posted is for the users and it might be limiting my search results since I query it through a program
3. Also I like to retrieve posts from the given date range. I am not sure if this is possible with my approach.

Appreciate any help in this regard. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

- Assuming you don't need to go back to the history and scrap all the data I would just stick to tags
  http://en.wordpress.com/tags/
- I would crawl it every day get the most popular tags (by font size) then on each tag get the articles published in the past 24 hours
- On each post get all the comments and search for your keywords

Would that work? if not please share more details

Good luck